# Задержка в потоках SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь реализовать отрисовку объектов в `SurfaceView` по `touch`.
При этом, каждый тач порождает отдельный поток, в котором объект с ускорением падает вниз.

Возник вопрос, возможно ли в потоке для `SurfaceView` создать задержку, чтобы она не мешала другим потокам? Сейчас она отрисовывает мгновенно все этапы передвижения фигуры.

Код:

```
class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private DrawThread drawThread;
    boolean Draw = false;
    public float X1, Y1, evX,evY;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder());
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        drawThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        drawThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                drawThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        evX = event.getX();
        evY = event.getY();

        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.surfaceCreated(getHolder());
            Draw = true;
            X1 = evX;
            Y1 = evY;
            break;
        default:
        }
        return true; //processed
    }


    class DrawThread extends Thread {

        public Paint mPaint = new Paint();

        private boolean running = false;
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        int c = 1;

        public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

        public void DrawOkr(Canvas mcanvas, float X, float Y){
            float pX1, pX2, pX3, pX4;
            float pY1, pY2, pY3, pY4;

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

            pX1 = X - 15;
            pY1 = Y;

            pX2 = X;
            pY2 = Y - 30;

            mcanvas.drawLine(pX1, pY1, pX2, pY2, mPaint);

            pX3 = X + 15;
            pY3 = Y;
            mcanvas.drawLine(pX2, pY2, pX3, pY3, mPaint);

            pX4 = X;
            pY4 = Y + 30;

            mcanvas.drawLine(pX3, pY3, pX4, pY4, mPaint);
            mcanvas.drawLine(pX4, pY4, pX1, pY1, mPaint);
            mcanvas.drawLine(pX1, pY1, pX3, pY3, mPaint);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas;
            while (running) {
                canvas = null;
                try {
                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder)
                    {
                        if (canvas == null)
                            continue;

                        DrawOkr(canvas, evX, evY);
                        c = 1;
                        while(evY < canvas.getHeight())
                        {
                            evY = evY + 10;
                            if (evY > canvas.getHeight())
                            {
                                if (c <= 3)
                                {
                                    evX = evX + 15;
                                    evY = (canvas.getHeight() - (60/c));
                                    c++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    evY = canvas.getHeight();
                                }
                            }
                            DrawOkr(canvas, evX, evY);

                        }
                        running = false;
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thread.sleep(xxxx) не подходит?

Comment: @АндрейГ. Пытался, тогда полностью блокируется SurfaceView, и по touch событию не происходит создание дополнительных потоков. Не говоря уже о том, что само полотно SurfaceView вызывается с задержкой.

Comment: @АндрейГ. немного поправлюсь, задержка работает, но она просто не показывает ничего расчетное количество времени, а потом сразу выдает всю картинку.

Comment: Да, поэтому вам нужно, я так думаю, создать некий цикл, который будет рисовать определённое количество за один раз и как то рассчитать задержку, чтобы получилось плавное рисование.
Ну типа чем вместо 25 сразу, рисуем 1/25 пути и ставим задержку 40. Таким образом за 1000 миллисеунд (1 секунду) получим рисование 25.
Мне так кажется, могу ошибаться.